# How can I change terminal font size in i3 on arch linux?

Tags: terminal, fonts, arch-linux

I installed xorg, I can successfully `startx` and I installed i3 on arch linux. How can can I change, or more specifically; increase the size, in the default terminal in i3? From the [i3wm documentation](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html) it states I can do the following: `font pango:Terminus 11px` but that results in a `font: command not found` error. I hope someone can guide me in the right direction.

** ***EDIT*** **

I was able to change the font and font size but the font is still small. I am on a 13" laptop with a high-res screen. Also, arch linux is installed on a virtualbox. Guest additions were installed and work. I created `~/.Xresources` file with the following

```
xterm*faceName: dina-font
xterm*fontSize: 20
```

I also edited my `~/.xinitrc` file with

```
xrdb -load /home/username/.Xresources & 
exec i3
```

When I start X, i3 load with the settings from `~/.Xresources`: dina-font (Monospace) and size 20. However it is still small.

When I increase the size using the `xterm*fontSize` setting or Ctrl + Right click, only the cursor block gets bigger but the actual font does not. Perhaps this is a screen resolution at this point?

Comment: You *might* be running xterm, but there is not enough information to see what the actual default terminal is.  The *pango* setting won't work for xterm.  Each  of the possible terminal emulators will have a different way to specify the font.

Comment: I hope you have changed `username` to your actual username.

Answer (score 1):

It's not fully clear if you want to change the font in your terminal (are you using xterm?) or in your vconsole before issuing `startx` command.

To change the font size in xterm:

```
xterm*faceSize: 23
```

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't changed anything with i3wm then you're probably launching i3-sensible-terminal. Check your `~/.i3/config` and see what you have entered for the line `$mod+return` that will tell you which terminal you're launching and if you want to you can change it there to something you may already understand (i.e. xterm). this terminal then pulls up a shell.

The shell you're using is going to affect how you can change font size/style. Type `ps` and see which shell you're running. After that you can google around how to set the font settings for the specific shell.

Answer (score 0):

As a newbie, i had this problem :)
What i did was:

1. Create .Xresources file under home folder:

   `vim ~/.Xresources`
2. Write:

   `xterm*faceName: monospace:pixelsize=44`
3. Save & quit
4. Reload xterm with:

   `xrdb ~/.Xresources`

And then i did quit i3 ($mod+shift+e) and logged in again. That took a while and then the font + fontsize were changed.